# Amazon RDS Postgresql 9.5 CPU increase

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, performance, postgresql-performance

I run a task in my Python application of ~100K jobs which takes around 5 hours, since the beginning my in RDS instance CPU starts growing...

Instance type: Postgresql 9.5 | db.t2.large

[image]

I have the following performance counters:

CPU 68.1%
Memory 7,250 MB
Storage 4,010 MB
Read IOPS 0.55/sec
Write IOPS 27.2/sec
Swap Usage 0 MB

Settings:

```
max_connections {DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}
pg_stat_statements.track ALL
shared_preload_libraries  pg_stat_statements
tcp_keepalives_count  1
tcp_keepalives_idle   120
tcp_keepalives_interval 60
temp_buffers  {DBInstanceClassMemory/512}
track_activity_query_size 2048
```

I'm using pganalyze to monitor database.

Any pointers how to debug CPU increase?
All 100K job consist of same queries (1 inserts/4 updates per job).

Comment: Just a guess but PG mvcc implementation can cause more writes to disk, if you do many updates, take a look at the dead tuples statistics on your tables - it might be very large causing a load on the storage layer which manifest as cpu io-waits (which show as cpu load in monitors)

Comment: Does the CPU utilization cause other problems?

Comment: Yes, if I have more than 100K queries, DB response takes very long time > 1000 ms and application start acting weird. Seems to be a problem with my UPDATE statements which are looking for a non-indexed field. Will add Index and verify